# Magnet Links open Deluge but don't start the torrent

Tags: deluge, torrent-client

Initially, clicking a magnet link would do nothing, but after some research, I ran the following command:

```
xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

Now, as the title says, clicking a magnet link will open Deluge, but it won't actually start the torrent.

I can't find any behavior similar to this and I'm stumped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe, setting "Add torrents in Paused state" is enabled? It's located in "Edit > Preferences > Downloads".

Comment: @andrybak Nope, its disabled. It only launches the program as if I just clicked the Deluge launch icon. I still have to manually add the URL

Comment: Had the same problem .... been messing with "xdg-mime"  and other suggested methods ... neither worked for me. When I open magnet from Firefox - easy peasy, but it doesn't work with Chrome

Comment: Likely this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1453174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the magnet link and Deluge opens, does it actually add the torrent to the queue?

I currently have the issue where clicking a magnet link will open Deluge but will not add the torrent.

As a workaround, you should be able to right click on the magnet link and copy the link address, then in Deluge go to File > Add Torrent > URL

Comment: still does download the torrent file, the magnet url is shown, that's it

Answer (score 1):

Non answer here, but I cant add a comment yet so adding this as an [non] answer.

For Chrome, it seems to run "xdg-open" when a magnet link is clicked with the magnet URL passed in as the $1 to the command.  This does successfully trigger Deluge to open, but it fails to actually add the torrent.

It used to work just fine for me in 14.04 and I just recently took the dive and upgraded to 14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.04 and now it's broken.  So perhaps seeing that xdg-open is a rather simple wrapper to call Deluge, perhaps something changed with how deluge wants the magnet link passed to it from xdg-open?

Update: Looks like the culprit [could be with gvfs-open](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196127), which is what apparently xdg-open calls.  Looks like 1.22 worked, 1.24 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution for same problem, You have to set Download location on *Preferences> Downloads> Download to* : add the valid path on text box and then Its working...